# Login Activity: SharedPreferences or SQLite

Tags: android

I'm new and trying to create a login activity (username & password) in android. Just want to ask which is more fitting to use? Using sharedPreferences or using SQLite? In terms of security and size. I already have a SQLite database for data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a database then you can use the database for your login functionality. If there will be a lot of users for your app that are login from the same device then I think the database is more faster, but I don't believe there will be more than 5 users/device.

Both of the methods are secured, as I know you can't get the database file of an app from the phone and neither the preferences..

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I'm limiting my app to one account only.

Comment: Yep, security wise they are identical. The shared prefs are just a normal XML file. Both the preferences and the database files are stored under `/data/data/your.packagename`. If the users phone is not rooted, he can't access that. If it is, he can access both without a problem.

Comment: If your are limiting your app to only one account then you can make the login feature with which method you know and you are comfortable the most :)